# Functions are big only over exponentially small sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\mu(\{x\in[0,1]\mid |f_n(x)|>1/n\})\leq 1/2^n$ for all integers $n\geq 1$. Is it true that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=0$ for almost every $x$?

I tried to apply the Chebyshev's inequality, but it doesn't work out. I can't find any counterexample either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you want. Suppose $\mu$ is a finite measure on $\Omega,\Sigma)$ and that you have meeasurable sets $E_n$ so that
$$\sum_n \mu(E_n) < \infty.$$
Then $\mu(\limsup_{n\to\infty} E_n) = 0$.  Recall that
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} E_n = \{x\in\Omega\,|\, x\in E_n\,\,\hbox{infinitely often}\}.$$